# Optimize a subset operation of a nested list

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyr

is it possible to improve the speed of the last subset operation in this code?
This code fetches a small portion of Open Streetmap data, searches for all the roads that have names and creates a new **osm** o bject that only contains the roads.
Im interrested in optimizing the last bit of the code:

```
highway_subset <- subset(muc, ids = highway_subset_ids)
```

> class(muc)

> [1] "osmar" "list"

muc is a list of lists end each element of the list has an id that is used to create a subset.

Here is the complete example:

```
library("osmar")
src <- osmsource_api(url = "https://api.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/")
muc_bbox <- center_bbox(11.575278, 48.137222, 1000, 1000)
muc <- get_osm(muc_bbox, src)

highway_subset_ids <- subset(muc, way_ids = find(muc, way(tags(k == "highway"))))
highway_subset_ids <- find(highway_subset_ids, way(tags(k == "name")))
highway_subset_ids <- find_down(muc, way(highway_subset_ids))
highway_subset <- subset(muc, ids = highway_subset_ids)
```

Thank you very much in advance.

**UPDATE**

If you have trouble with ssl, try to copy paste the following code example. It is as minimum as i could make it.

The line i would like to optimize is this one:

> **final_subset <- subset(highway_subset, ids = highway_subset_ids)**

```
library("osmar")

highway_subset <-
  structure(list(nodes = structure(list(
          attrs = structure(
            list(
              id = numeric(0),
              visible = character(0),
              timestamp = structure(
                list(
                  sec = numeric(0),
                  min = integer(0),
                  hour = integer(0),
                  mday = integer(0),
                  mon = integer(0),
                  year = integer(0),
                  wday = integer(0),
                  yday = integer(0),
                  isdst = integer(0),
                  zone = character(0),
                  gmtoff = integer(0)
                ),
                class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt")
              ),
              version = numeric(0),
              changeset = numeric(0),
              user = structure(integer(0), .Label = character(0), class = "factor"),
              uid = structure(
                integer(0),
                .Label = c("2455020", "2590140", "367380"),
                class = "factor"
              ),
              lat = numeric(0),
              lon = numeric(0)
            ),
            row.names = integer(0),
            class = "data.frame"
          ),
          tags = structure(
            list(
              id = numeric(0),
              k = structure(integer(0), .Label = character(0), class = "factor"),
              v = structure(integer(0), .Label = character(0), class = "factor")
            ),
            row.names = integer(0),
            class = "data.frame"
          )
        ),
        class = c("nodes", "osmar_element", "list")
      ),
      ways = structure(
        list(
          attrs = structure(
            list(
              id = c(105071009, 366457476),
              visible = c("true", "true"),
              timestamp = structure(
                list(
                  sec = c(10, 48),
                  min = c(54L, 15L),
                  hour = c(13L, 20L),
                  mday = c(4L, 15L),
                  mon = c(2L, 4L),
                  year = 117:116,
                  wday = c(6L, 0L),
                  yday = c(62L, 135L),
                  isdst = 0:1,
                  zone = c("CET", "CEST"),
                  gmtoff = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_)
                ),
                class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt")
              ),
              version = c(15, 5),
              changeset = c(46573027, 39338422),
              user = structure(
                2:1,
                .Label = c("bjoern262", "saerdnaer"),
                class = "factor"
              ),
              uid = structure(
                4:3,
                .Label = c("367380",
                           "64536", "651621", "6998"),
                class = "factor"
              )
            ),
            row.names = c(2L,
                          4L),
            class = "data.frame"
          ),
          tags = structure(
            list(
              id = c(
                105071009,
                105071009,
                105071009,
                105071009,
                105071009,
                105071009,
                105071009,
                105071009,
                105071009,
                105071009,
                105071009,
                366457476,
                366457476,
                366457476,
                366457476,
                366457476
              ),
              k = structure(
                c(1L, 2L, 3L,
                  4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 11L),
                .Label = c(
                  "conveying",
                  "description",
                  "highway",
                  "incline",
                  "indoor",
                  "layer",
                  "level",
                  "oneway",
                  "operator",
                  "ref",
                  "tunnel"
                ),
                class = "factor"
              ),
              v = structure(
                c(6L,
                  9L, 10L, 4L, 11L, 3L, 2L, 11L, 8L, 7L, 11L, 5L, 11L, 1L, 1L,
                  11L),
                .Label = c(
                  "-3",
                  "-3;-4",
                  "-4",
                  "down",
                  "footway",
                  "forward",
                  "MP19",
                  "MVG",
                  "Rolltreppe MP19",
                  "steps",
                  "yes"
                ),
                class = "factor"
              )
            ),
            row.names = 4:19,
            class = "data.frame"
          ),
          refs = structure(
            list(
              id = c(105071009, 105071009, 366457476,
                     366457476, 366457476),
              ref = c(3270556979, 1211172719, 3270556979,
                      3704371485, 3704371444)
            ),
            row.names = c(20L, 21L, 68L, 69L,
                          70L),
            class = "data.frame"
          )
        ),
        class = c("ways", "osmar_element",
                  "list")
      ),
      relations = structure(
        list(
          attrs = structure(
            list(
              id = numeric(0),
              visible = character(0),
              timestamp = structure(
                list(
                  sec = numeric(0),
                  min = integer(0),
                  hour = integer(0),
                  mday = integer(0),
                  mon = integer(0),
                  year = integer(0),
                  wday = integer(0),
                  yday = integer(0),
                  isdst = integer(0),
                  zone = character(0),
                  gmtoff = integer(0)
                ),
                class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt")
              ),
              version = numeric(0),
              changeset = numeric(0),
              user = structure(integer(0), .Label = character(0), class = "factor"),
              uid = structure(
                integer(0),
                .Label = c(
                  "137242",
                  "161619",
                  "2455020",
                  "2590140",
                  "531886",
                  "72235",
                  "8748",
                  "9451067"
                ),
                class = "factor"
              )
            ),
            row.names = integer(0),
            class = "data.frame"
          ),
          tags = structure(
            list(
              id = numeric(0),
              k = structure(integer(0), .Label = character(0), class = "factor"),
              v = structure(integer(0), .Label = character(0), class = "factor")
            ),
            row.names = integer(0),
            class = "data.frame"
          ),
          refs = structure(
            list(
              id = numeric(0),
              type = structure(integer(0), .Label = character(0), class = "factor"),
              ref = numeric(0),
              role = structure(integer(0), .Label = character(0), class = "factor")
            ),
            row.names = integer(0),
            class = "data.frame"
          )
        ),
        class = c("relations",
                  "osmar_element", "list")
      )
    ),
    class = c("osmar", "list")
  )
highway_subset_ids <- find_down(highway_subset, way(highway_subset$ways$attrs$id))
final_subset <- subset(highway_subset, ids = highway_subset_ids)
```

Thank you!

Comment: `get_osm(muc_bbox, src)` fails with message "error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version"

Comment: Strange.. it works on my machine.

Comment: Uwe i updated the question and added a version where you dont need a connection. It is minimal though.

Comment: thank your for updating the question but I need more guidance / context / background / motivation to go into the right direction. What is the objective of your optimization? Speed? Memory consumption? Why do you find an optimization is required, etc? Thank you.

Comment: If speed is an issue, have you tried to profile your production code?

Comment: it´s about speed. I did profile my code and this part is currently is a problem. I have to make subsets on a large data several times and those times add up. Memory is not the issue.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50433477/9841389) might be of interest regarding the ssl issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I profiled your code

```r
library("osmar")
src <- osmsource_api(url = "https://api.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/")
muc_bbox <- center_bbox(11.575278, 48.137222, 1000, 1000)
muc <- get_osm(muc_bbox, src)

system.time(
  highway_subset_ids <- subset(muc, way_ids = find(muc, way(tags(k == "highway"))))
)
# 0.157
system.time(
  highway_subset_ids <- find(highway_subset_ids, way(tags(k == "name")))
)
# 0.001
system.time(
  highway_subset_ids <- find_down(muc, way(highway_subset_ids))
)
# 0.008
system.time(
  highway_subset <- subset(muc, ids = highway_subset_ids)
)
# 0.025
```

As you can see, for me the last `subset` is not the bottleneck but the first one  is (6 times more expensive).

The internal data are not really big

- `nodes` 15157 rows
- `ways` 2938 rows
- `tags` 11966 rows
- `relations` 350 rows
- another `tags` 3270 rows

You mentioned you need to do subset multiple times. The problem to address might be to try to "vectorize" your code. I don't mean obvious `lapply` but extracting internal data.frames, rbinding them, then doing subset only once, and if needed splitting them again. `data.table` can be employed here to bring extra speed. It will be much more beneficial than using data.table subset in a loop on 15000 rows only, where benefits will be much smaller.

To understand how to "vectorize" that code, you need to understand how osmar `subset` works. That is not that difficult if you look at source code https://github.com/cran/osmar/blob/master/R/osmar-subsetting.R

- try to take out data.frames from all objects to subset
- `rbindlist` them
- `subset` them using `[.data.table`
- split if needed
- turn into original objects if needed

Also note that `osmar` package is quite old, dated 2013, it has indirect dependencies of package like `sp` which is quite actively developed. You may expect some issues related to breaking changes that may have been introduced in `osmar` dependencies in last 7 years.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestions. What dou you mean by "subset them using [.data.table" ? I mean could you please provide a small example ?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to provide an example of vectorizing the code on the function subset_ways from osmar code? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Regarding first subset: it is not a problem in my code since it is an operation i do only once, but the last subset is done repeadedly

Comment: Please extend your example code by providing loop that does the last subset.

Comment: Reproducible if possible

Comment: Im sorry but that loop doesn't add any new information sadly. Furthermore it's difficult to provide a data set of osm objekt since even for a couple of nodes it creates a huge print out so i can't put it here. If you don't have an ssl issue, the example in original question is complete and reproducible.

Comment: I don't have ssl problem, your code runs fine for me. I just don't want to be guessing what you are precisely doing before investing my time into it.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much for your effort and suggestions so far. You don't have to :)  As i mentioned earlier: the problem is that last subset. The whole  loop does not give anything additional on information.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any ideas to speed up single `subset`, even if possible then speed up will likely to be marginal. Big gains are possible if you get rid of loop and do _batch `subset`_.

Comment: Hmm yes I was thinking about it. The problem is: I can't know before hand  how many steps the loop will take. It's always different.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it probably is possible. You can see the structure of the osmar objects by entering `str(muc)` in the console and you can see the code used to do the subsetting by running `osmar:::subset.osmar` which is made of component functions like `osmar:::subset_ways`. All of it seems to be written in base R and could be sped up with for instance `data.table`.

The strategy might be to work out a more efficient way to do this whole set of operations in one go:

```
highway_subset_ids <- subset(muc, way_ids = find(muc, way(tags(k == "highway"))))
highway_subset_ids <- find(highway_subset_ids, way(tags(k == "name")))
highway_subset_ids <- find_down(muc, way(highway_subset_ids))
highway_subset <- subset(muc, ids = highway_subset_ids)
```

Exactly where you focus and how you do it depends on the details of the rest of your project and what you are actually trying to do.